# ReactJS - redirect on the login page if session expired

Tags: node.js, reactjs, session, redux

I have followed some tutorial to build an authentication in React, Node and Redux. The basic functionality works, however, when I keep the application open and then get back to it (when the session expired), I get this error message:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'uploadURL' of undefined
```

Then I refresh the page and I get this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Then, I refresh the page again and I am finally redirected on the homepage. The first 2 errors are a problem I am not sure how to get rid off them.

This is what my code looks like:
...

```
class Event extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        ...
    }

    UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
        // I thought this if-block will redirect the user if the session is expired
        if(!this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
            console.log('unauthorized');
            this.props.history.push('/');
        }

        this.uppy2 = new Uppy({ id: 'uppy2', autoProceed: true, debug: true })
                            .use(Tus, { endpoint: 'https://master.tus.io/files/' })
                            .on('complete', (result) => {
                                console.log(`Upload complete! We’ve uploaded these files: ${result.successful[0].uploadURL}`);
                            });
    }
    ...
}
Event.propTypes = {
    registerUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth,
    errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{ registerUser })(withRouter(Event))
```

Here's the Redux code (I am beginner with the MERN stack):

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_ERRORS, SET_CURRENT_USER } from './types'; // we list here the actions we'll use
import setAuthToken from '../../setAuthToken';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

export const registerUser = (user, history) => dispatch => {
    axios.post('/api/users/register', user)
            .then(res => history.push('/login'))
            .catch(err => {
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_ERRORS,
                    payload: err.response.data
                });
            });
}

export const loginUser = (user) => dispatch => {
    axios.post('/api/users/login', user)
        .then(res => {
            //console.log(res.data);
            const { token } = res.data;
            localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token);
            setAuthToken(token);
            const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
            dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_ERRORS,
                payload: err.response.data
            });
        });
}

export const setCurrentUser = decoded => {
    return {
        type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
        payload: decoded
    }
}

export const logoutUser = (history) => dispatch => {
    localStorage.removeItem('jwtToken');
    setAuthToken(false);
    dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));
    history.push('/login');
}
```

How do I prevent the errors happening when the session is expired?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you show your code in detail? You can write code in codesandbox.io.

Answer (score 0):

ComponentWillMount won't be called if the page is loaded before the session expires. I suspect the first error is caused by some missing data because the request with the expired token failed. You would need to make sure the 401 or 403 error is handled and clear out the Redux state so the login page is shown when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure with this part `!this.props.auth.isAuthenticated`. Did you use `mapDispatchToProps` and `connect` for redux? You need to do this in your Event class to reach your reducer.

Also the thing that you can do is, before rendering your jsx code, declare a variable like `let redirect = null` and if `!this.props.auth.isAuthenticated` is correct, set this redirect variable to `redirect = <Redirect to="/" />` (If you use browser routing!) and use this variable like this,

```
render() {
  return (
    {redirect}
  )
}
```

Comment: hello, yes - I used it, I just updated the OP to show it, it's in the end of the component. As of the variable and redirect - I would rather like to find the reason why the error is raised, I must be overlooking something... it's driving me crazy.

Comment: I guess, when session is expired there is no any value returns with `result.successful[0].uploadURL`. I think, the problem with if condition. Write true in your condition if it works or not. Just for checking. It should redirect even if session is not expired but just try. Also do you see this `isAuthenticated` changes in Redux Dev Tool? @user2932090